# Why does ios dismiss all my UITextView fonts

Tags: ios, storyboard, xcode5, uitextview

All my UITextViews are created through the storyboard. I used to have the fonts as body. But now I want to change them to System Fonts. So I go to storyboard and change them there. When I run the app, the new fonts are ignored completely. I even change the sizes to 22 just to see some effects but nothing happens. Any ideas what sort of global setting might be doing this?

Comment: clean your project or clean derived data folder then try again.

Comment: If you changed the font in code it overrides anything you did on storyboard, could that be it?